# We were discussing the matter/about the matter/about the whole matter/totally about the matter

Tags: prepositions

Which of the following sentences is correct?

1. We were discussing about the matter.
2. We were discussing about the whole matter.
3. We were discussing the matter.
4. We were discussing totally about the matter.

This is a job entry exam question.

Comment: Welcome to ell, Imran. We expect people to do a little research before asking a question. In this case, you could look at the entry for **discuss** in a dictionary that provides examples, for example this one: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/discuss If that doesn't provide the information that you require, edit the question to explain in detail what you don't understand, and provide links to the research that you did not find helpful.

Comment: The expectation of prior research is especially true when the question is about homework or any kind of exam!

Comment: Actually the exam was over a week ago. I am just clearing the answers from a reliable source like this forum. If I made a mistake, then this post should be deleted. Thank you very much for clearing me out here.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to ell, Imran. I agree with the comments made. However, my answer is as follows:

When you discuss something with someone, you talk to them seriously about it (The Free Dictionary).

As the verb discuss takes no preposition, all the options, except #3, are not correct.

The use of the adverb totally also sounds a bit inappropriate with the verb discuss.  You can use  fully, thoroughly, or extensively instead in front of the verb as follows:

We were fully/thoroughly/exhaustively/extensively discussing the matter.

Comment: Thank you very much fro clearing me out here. I couldn't find any reliable sources for searching this type of grammatical explanations. So, I posted here.